# Is it possible that many ports of a switch to have the same MAC address in its MAC address table?

Tags: networking, portforwarding, mac-address, switching

I found that it is possible to do so by MAC spoofing. Apart from spoofing, is it possible? If so, in what instances is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

A switch learns unicast MAC addresses into its *source address table* or *CAM table* by inspecting each frame's source address. A MAC address association already present on another switch port is *moved* to the current frame's ingress port.

In no case does a properly working switch associate *multiple* ports with the same MAC. Accordingly, a frame addressed to a specific MAC address is always forwarded out of the last switch port that has received a frame from that address. If the associated port changes rapidly it's somewhat random where a frame destined for that MAC address ends up.

Some managed switches track the learning behavior and report flapping/duplicate MACs when they change port association repeatedly in a short time period. There may also be some contingency scheme for where to forward frames to such an address.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to investigate a some 'oddities' regarding the learning process of a switch. While I agree with @Zac67' answer, I disagree that

> *In no case does a properly working switch associate multiple ports with the same MAC.*

Here's what I found and the topology I used:

```
      switch_3
         |         
       trunk
    vlans 10 & 20
         |
      switch_2
         |         
       trunk
    vlans 10 & 20
         |
      switch_1
    /        \
access      access 
vlan 10      vlan20
/               \
Linux_1        Linux_2
```

The test is pretty simple:
Send ethernet frames from both Linux_1 and Linux_2 with the same source MAC address, towards switch_1. For this purpose you may use some traffic generator sucy as python-scapy. switch_1 forwards the traffic to switch_2, which forwards it further to switch_3

Now, looking at their MAC address tables:

**switch_1**:

```
Switch#show mac address-table 
          Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
----    -----------       --------    -----
  10    0000.0dab.2115    DYNAMIC     Et0/1
  20    0000.0dab.2115    DYNAMIC     Et0/0
Total Mac Addresses for this criterion: 2
```

As you can see, on switch_1, the same source MAC address is learned on two distinct ports.

**switch_2**:

```
Switch#show mac address-table 
          Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
----    -----------       --------    -----
  10    0000.0dab.2115    DYNAMIC     Et0/0
  20    0000.0dab.2115    DYNAMIC     Et0/0
Total Mac Addresses for this criterion: 2
```

the output from switch_2 shows that it is also possible for the same source MAC address to be learned multiple times, on the same port.

Why this happens:
I did some research and it turns out that the behaviour Zac67 described is true if:

- there is one single VLAN we are talking about
- the switch doesn't support VLANs
- the VLANs share the same forwarding database (MAC table), implementation known as Shared VLAN Learning

In my situation, the switch is capable of Independent VLAN learning, which basically means that there is one separate forwarding database (MAC table) for each VLAN. Basically, VLAN 10 and VLAN 20 have separate MAC tables and the learning process one VLAN occurs independently of the other VLAN.